# Google Cloud Function / Firebase Function deployment stops working: "unexpected end of file"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Deploying our Firebase Function suddenly stopped working recently. Running `firebase functions:log` provided an insight that was not very helpful:

> 2022-02-15T06:53:12.421579Z E XXX:
> {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Build
> failed: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 \n\ngzip:
> stdin: unexpected end of file\ntar: Child returned status 1\ntar:
> Error is not recoverable: exiting now; Error ID:
> 08522105"},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"XXXX"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"XXXX"}

The deployment works fine for other projects, but fails even for older versions of this project (ones that have been deployed successfully in the past).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firebase log was not useful at all, but since Functions are built using "Google Cloud Build" I was able to get more insight into what's wrong by opening the Logs Explorer in Google Cloud Console. Select the resource type "Cloud Build" and there you will find logs of each build step and which one failed.

[image: Google Cloud Log Explorer]

In this case, it fails to fetch the yarn-version specific in our package.json (1.22). Changing it to "1.22.17" (latest as of now) fixed the build.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "14",
    "npm": "8.1",
    "yarn": "1.22.17"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

I received a 404 error from `gcloud.functions.deploy` on deploy:

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...
.
For Cloud Build Stackdriver Logs, visit: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=x-xxx-dev&advancedFilter=resource.type%3Dbuild%0Aresource.labels.build_id%3D35aac420-xx-4cd1-b7be-blah%0AlogName%3Dprojects%2Fxxx-xxx-dev%2Flogs%2Fcloudbuild
................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
```

The root cause error is not visible here, but if you click on the Stackdriver logs link in the console output, there will be more details.  In my case, the root error was that yarn 2.4.3 couldn't be downloaded @ https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v2.4.3/yarn-v2.4.3.tar.gz

[image: stackdriver logs scerenshot]

I did not expect to be using yarn 2 (berry) at this point, but in my `package.json` I was not explicit:

```
 "engines": {
    ...
    "yarn": ">=1.22.0"
  },
```

By changing to accept only version 1, the problem was resolved:

```
 "engines": {
    ...
    "yarn": "^1.22.0"
  },
```

I still don't understand why npm resolved this missing version.